# JavaScript variables used inside html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have to make a mock-up website for a school assignment. The website involves a search feature. For the assignment, the search feature does not have to be fully functional; So for the mock-up, I want to have an iframe that will change the src="" value after a button is pushed. At first, the iframe will display an image, then after the client/user enters something (any string the input doesnt matter) and hits "search", I want the src for the iframe to change. I was wondering if there was any way to do this using javascript. I'm fairly new and know very little about javascript. The iframe that I need to change has and id of search_frame. This is my code:

```
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HOME.CSS"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="top" >
      <a href="" id="LOGO">
        <img alt="LOGO" height="37" src="LOGO.JPG" width="342" />
      </a>
        <img id="Cheetah_Logo" alt="cheetah_logo" height="29" src="Cheetah_Corner.PNG" width="205" /><a id="CHEETAH_LINK">
      </a>
  </div>

      <div  id="center">
        <div id="Left_Section">
            <div id="checkBox">
                <form>
                    <input type="radio"/>Text-Books
                    <input type="radio"/>eBooks
                    <input type="radio"/>Class-Notes
                    <input type="radio"/>Exams
                    <input type="radio"/>Tutors
                    <input type="radio"/>Software
                    <input type="radio"/>Homework
                    <input type="radio"/>Free-Stuff
                    <input type="radio"/>Events
                    <input type="radio"/>Other 
                    <a id="Advanced" href="http://Home.html">Advanced Search</a>
                </form>
                <div id="search_Div">
                    <form id="Search">
                        <input id="search_Bar" type="text" />
                        <button>Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="search_results">
                <iframe id="search_frame" scrolling="yes" src="image.png">
                    Your system does not support frames
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="links">
            <a href="Product.html" id="link_product">

            </a>
            <a href="profile_2.html" id="link_profile">
                <img id="profile_button" alt="profile_button" src="profile_button.jpg" />
            </a>
            <a id="click_here" href="profile_2.html">
                Click here to view your profile!
            </a>
            </div>
      </div>

  <div id="bottom">
      <center>
        <img src="bottom_bar.JPG" alt="bottom_bar" />
      </center>
  </div>

</div>
<div>
    <img src="Left_Filler.JPG" alt="Left_Filler" id="Left_Filler"/>
    <img src="Right_Filler.JPG" alt="Right_Filler" id="Right_Filler"/>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the idea general idea of the type of script I want to run:

This will set the iframe to the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rowdy(num){
    variable1='Rowdy.jpeg';
    return variable1;
    }
</script>
```

This is my mocksearch once the button is pushed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mockSearch(var1)
    {
        var1='Results_Mock_CSS.css';
        return var1;    
    }
</script>
```

I know these are incorrect, but I was thinking there might be a way to put the function calls inside the src for the iframe, any help, guidance, or ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have click event on your button like,

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="SearchClicked();"/>
```

And that click can change the source like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SearchClicked() {
        document.getElementById('search_frame').src = 'Rowdy.jpg';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, kill the "form" element as that basically indicates a trip back to the server which you don't want (sortof, you may want it back later but leave that until you understand it).  Then install an onclick handler for the button that locates the iframe and updates the src attribute.

Something like

```
        <div id="search_Div">
        <input id="search_Bar" type="text" />
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('search_frame').src='Rowdy.jpeg';">
           Search</button>
        </div>
```

will do it.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer states, you could use the onClick property. You could also use jQuery magic (which would be less efficient, but for a school project, the difference is negligible).

First, in the head, you'd have to import jQuery with the statement

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then, you could put right after it

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $('#search_frame').attr('src', 'Rowdy.jpg');
        }
    }
</script>
```

to bind a method to the click event on the button.